# Fill forwards or backwards depending on another row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
 loc status   ID
0   LA    NaN  NaN
1  CHC    NaN  NaN
2  NYC    ARR   32
3  CHC    DEP   45
4  SEA    NaN  NaN
```

I am trying to fill the missing values in the ID column depending on the status column.  If the status column is "ARR": I want to fill backwards and if the status column is "DEP": I want to fill forwards so my final dataframe would look like:

```
  loc status  ID
0   LA    NaN  32
1  CHC    NaN  32
2  NYC    ARR  32
3  CHC    DEP  45
4  SEA    NaN  45
```

I have been trying to accomplish this by using 2 for loops to loop through both columns, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
dt.ID.fillna(method='bfill').fillna(method='ffill')
```

It will fill NA values with preceding non-NA values (in reverse first and then forwards)

Edit:

Maybe this is what you're looking for (based on comments)

```
dt.ID.fillna(method='ffill').where(dt.ID.notnull() | (dt.status.shift(1) == 'DEP'), dt.ID.fillna(method='bfill').where(dt.ID.notnull() | (dt.status.shift(-1) == 'ARR')))
```

Its not very readable, but should give a general idea

Comment: That works for this specific example dataframe, however it will not work for all scenarios as sometimes "DEP" occurs before "ARR" - so I would need to front fill before I back fill

Comment: Not sure I follow, what would you do if you get a DEP, NaN, ARR sequence?

Comment: I would fill forwards on the NaN value due to the DEP coming before the ARR

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this by dividing your dataframe `df` according to whether you want to forward fill or backward fill those rows:

create two copies of your df, one with everything forward filled and the other with everything back filled

```
fill_forward = df.status.fillna(method='ffill') 
fill_backward = df.status.fillna(method='bfill')
```

get the indices of the rows where forward filling resulted in rows being filled with `'DEP'` and the indices where back filling resulted in the rows being filled with `'ARR'` (ie. your two conditions)

```
forward_index = df.index[(df.status != fill_forward) & (fill_forward == 'DEP')]
backward_index = df.index[(df.status != fill_backward) & (fill_backward == 'ARR')]
```

update these indices so that they include the row directly preceding (used when forward filling) or the row directly following (used when backward filling).

```
forward_rows = sorted(list({ind for f in forward_index for ind in [f,f-1]}))
backward_rows = sorted(list({ind for b in backward_index for ind in [b,b+1]}))
```

fill (using the appropriate method) for each the list of indices and assign the updated values to the original df. note that by doing the forward fill first you are giving preference to forward filling when the indices overlap.

```
df.ID.iloc[forward_rows] = df.ID.iloc[forward_rows].fillna(method='ffill')
df.ID.iloc[backward_rows] = df.ID.iloc[backward_rows].fillna(method='bfill')

print(df)

   loc status    ID
0   LA    NaN  32.0
1  CHC    NaN  32.0
2  NYC    ARR  32.0
3  CHC    DEP  45.0
4  SEA    NaN  45.0
```